# Creating common code for Interface method for multiple activities - Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

I have an interface which has two methods to override.

There are two activities with different UI and both needs same functionality to override the methods of that Interface.

Now, I can do implement that Interface in my both the activities and can also override the methods in both the activities.

But I don't want to make my code duplicate. Is there any common way to make my overridden method common so that I need not to write the same code again?

In short, I want to write Interface implementation code only once which will be used by two separate activities. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just create a base activity class and implement this interface and in the another activities you may extend this base class, and if you need, override both. But i don't recommend it, because following the best practices is better avoid create new rules in your code, a while will get hardest to understand.   But the better approach is review you architecture, maybe you can just have one activity and a fragment, and share a viewModel between both.

Answer (score 1):

Why would an Activity need to implement an interface directly? It’s not the type of class that is typically passed around. In fact, it is very easy to create memory leaks and other bugs if you do so.

Implement the interface in a new class that you can reuse in each activity. That solves the code reuse problem.

Or if you don’t strictly need an interface, create Activity extension functions that perform the behavior you want. Then you have added the functionality to every Activity without duplicated code.